# Looping a file reader into new integers and producing a new set of results?

Tags: java, loops, text-files, filereader

Basically I am wanting to read some data from a text file place them in to multiple integers and do some calculations. Then loop the scanner to do it all again?

This is the code I have so far. The user will input a recommended amount, and the system should be able to calculate the ship cost.

```
int RM;
System.out.print("Enter the Recommened Journey cost: ");
RM = user_input.nextInt();


Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(task3.txt));

int shipID = inFile.nextInt();
int journeyID = inFile.nextInt();
int length = inFile.nextInt();
int numberOfCrew = inFile.nextInt();
int hourlyRate = inFile.nextInt();

int shipCost = hourlyRate*length*numberOfCrew;

if(shipCost<=RM)
{
    System.out.println("The ship is below the Recommeneded journey cost");
}
else if(shipCost>=RM)
{
    System.out.println("The ship is over the Recommeneded journey cost");
}
```

The text file would be layed out like this:

```
Monarch
M141
16
6
10.5
20
20
20
30

Princess
P103
18
5
40
45
45
60
80
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a way to get a `File` named *task3.txt*. Assuming you want the file in the user's home directory you could use something like

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "task3.txt");
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(f);
```

**Note**: [`Scanner(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29) will produce values from the given `File`.

Also, your proposed file layout starts with things that aren't `int`. You need to read those / haven't explained them.